# What's the difference between kernel object and event object in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

As far as I know , both of them are pointed by a HANDLE which can be manipulated by user.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the APIs used to create, synchronize and monitor threads in a multi threaded application rely on kernel objects, which are also used to manage memory and files. KO are OS resources such as process, threads, events, mutex, semaphores, shared memory and files etc.

Except creating or opening a kernel object. you refer it by a HANDLE rather than name. A HANDLE is 32-bit value which uniquely identify the kernel object.

Kernel object is in general and  **Event is one of the specific  kernel object**.

Refer

[Kernel Objects.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485(VS.85).aspx)

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655(VS.85).aspx).